# Starting a completely separate process in python

Tags: python, process

##### Background

I have a discord bot for my personal discord server with my friends, and have a command with it to start our Minecraft server.

##### The Problem

I need the command to start the Minecraft server to be run as a completely separate process, but nothing I have been trying has worked.

##### The Code

###### Python code

```
from discord import Interaction
from discord.ext import commands
...
class Minecraft(commands.Cog):
    """Minecraft commands"""
...
    @commands.slash_command(help="Starts a minecraft server")
    async def startmc(self, interaction: Interaction, server: str = "blox-smp"):
        """Starts a minecraft server"""
        
        # Check for valid server name
        if not server in ["blox-smp"]:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Invalid server name")
            return
        
        # Send status message
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Starting minecraft server {server}...")
        
        # Start the server
        if server == "blox-smp":
            # Need to start a separate process running the command: /var/mc-servers/blox_smp_1/run.sh y
...
```

###### run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get script directory
# Thanks Dave Dopson: https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/20382671
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd -- "$( dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )

# Get current working directory
CURRENT_WD="$PWD"

# Change to script directory
cd $SCRIPT_DIR

# Get from-program
FROM_PROGRAM=$1

if [ -z $FROM_PROGRAM ]
then
    FROM_PROGRAM="n"
fi

# Check active screen list for screen
sudo -u mc-user screen -ls | grep -i "blox_smp_1_screen"

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    # Update paper by running my pthon script
    python3 update-paper.py

    # Start the screen if it wasnt running before
    sudo -u mc-user screen -dmS blox_smp_1_screen /usr/lib/jvm/java-19-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms10G -Xmx20G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs -Daikars.new.flags=true -Dterminal.jline=false -jar paper.jar --nogui
fi

if [ "$FROM_PROGRAM" = "n" ]
then
    sudo -u mc-user screen -r blox_smp_1_screen
fi

# Change back to working directory
cd $CURRENT_WD
```

##### I've Tried...

- `subprocess.Popen()`
- `multiprocessing.Process(daemon=true)`
- `os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT)`
- Using `&` at the end of my commands

##### Edit 1

When I manually run the `/var/mc-servers/blox_smp_1/run.sh y` command, the server starts without the screen being connected. When I exit the terminal I ran `run.sh` in, the server stays on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` should work. You may need to use `start_new_session=True` so it isn't killed when your script exits.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't work for me. Though bashtop doesn't show the java process as a child process, it still exists when the bot is stopped/restarted.